# Codeigniter 4 Query Result Fetching

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to build report page with ci4 and I wanna print some data such as most popular city. here is my query `$db->query('SELECT city, COUNT(*) FROM events GROUP BY city HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY city ASC')` when I run the query on sequel pro it gives me right output like what I want. here is the result

| city | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| London | 5 |
| Dublin | 3 |
| Amsterdam | 1 |

what i want is printing them on view page like

1. London = 5
2. Dublin = 3
3. Amsterdam = 1

i think i need to work with arrays with loops but im realy confused. I tried some while loops but it gives me some error which is not relevant with this topic :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry for this question :( I need to sleep and rest a while before consider posting a problem or question on StackOverflow. as I mention its really simple, I just need to use foreach :)

```
foreach ($query->getResult('array') as $row) {
   echo $row['city'];
   $builder->where('city', $row['city']);
   echo $builder->countAllResults();
}
```